# IBM Watson Personality Insights Service : giving bad request as response

Tags: node.js, json, ibm-watson, personality-insights

I am using NodeJS SDK of watson to test Personality Insights Service but getting the following error:

```
> Error: { Bad Request: Invalid JSON input at line 1, column 2
>     at RequestWrapper.formatError (C:\Users\...\Desktop\..\..\ibm-analyser-cloud\node_modules\ibm-cloud-sdk-core\lib\request-wrapper.js:208:21)
>     at C:\Users\...\Desktop\..\..\ibm-analyser-cloud\node_modules\ibm-cloud-sdk-core\lib\request-wrapper.js:196:25
>     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)   name: 'Bad Request',   code: 400,   message: 'Invalid JSON input at
> line 1, column 2',   body:
> '{"code":400,"sub_code":"S00005","error":"Invalid JSON input at line
> 1, column 2"}',   headers:    { 'content-type': 'application/json',
>      'content-length': '81',
>      'access-control-allow-origin': '*',
>      'x-service-api-version': '4.0.2',
>      'x-service-build-number': '2020-01-20T06:02:53.029 UTC',
>      'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff',
>      'x-xss-protection': '1; mode=block',
>      'content-security-policy': 'default-src \'none\'',
>      pragma: 'no-cache',
>      'cache-control': 'no-store',
>      'x-service-pi-error-code': 'S00005',
>      'content-language': 'en-US',
>      'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains;',
>      'x-global-transaction-id': '833a39d917c511e8921aa5286669721c',
>      'x-dp-watson-tran-id': '833a39d917c511e8921aa5286669721c',
>      'x-edgeconnect-midmile-rtt': '289',
>      'x-edgeconnect-origin-mex-latency': '416',
>      date: 'Tue, 28 Jan 2020 02:59:53 GMT',
>      connection: 'close' } }
```

Below is the code snippet I am using :

> ```
> app.get("/personality-insights", function(req, res) {
>
>     const personalityInsights = new PersonalityInsightsV3({
>     version: '2017-10-13',
>     authenticator: new IamAuthenticator({
>       apikey: watsonKeyPersonalityInsights,
>     }),
>     url: watsonUrlPersonalityInsights,
>   });
>
>   let params = {
>     content: "I am very happy today",
>     content_type: 'text/plain',
>     raw_scores: true,
>     consumption_preferences: true
>   };
>
>     personalityInsights.profile(params, function(error, response) {
>     if (error)
>       console.log('Error:', error);
>     else
>       console.log(JSON.stringify(response, null, 2));
>     }
>   );
>
> });
> ```

this is a sample Node JS based snippet where I am providing the API credentials and the URL provided by the IBM cloud and making the request with a single line of input text. Everything seems correct but don't know why I am getting that error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the parameters were converted to lower camel case in v5. See the [MIGRATION](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/node-sdk/blob/master/MIGRATION-V5.md#all-parameter-names-changed-to-lower-camel-case---read-this) doc in the repo and the parameter details in the [API reference](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/personality-insights?code=node#get-profile)

- `contentType`
- `rawScores`
- `consumptionPreferences`